# Starting a Section on the same page in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm writing my dissertation in economics and would like to know how to start a new section on the same page.

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I use `\include{section 1..2..3}` so that I can work in different sections and include them with the command. So that would be:

```
\include{Section1}
\include{Section2}
\include{Section3}
\include{Section4}
\include{Section5}
\include{Section6}
\include{Section7}
\appendix
\include{Appendix}
```

I now want Section 2 to start where Section 1 ends (and so on) and not a fresh page. Any advice on the same? I'm not too sure what to do in this case. I guess the `\include` command changes things vis-a-vis other posts? Any help is appreciated! Thank you

I tried to add `\nopagebreak` in the main.txt file after `\include{Section x}` but it was of no use

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\input` to avoid the page break:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Section1.tex}
\section{title 1}
test
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Section2.tex}
\section{title 2}
test
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\input{Section1}
\input{Section2}


\end{document}
```

[image]